# How to change internal url to a new domain in Amazon Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I successfully deployed an ASP.NET Core 1.1 sample application [using AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.quickstart.html). At that time I did not have a domain name registered, so AWS created a default URL as, say, `http://awstestonlywebapp-dev.us-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`. Later I registered a domain via their Route53 service. **Question**: How do I use this new domain name so the above default URL gets replaced with the new domain name and user can access the above deployed website with the new domain e.g. `www.myDomain.com`?

**NOTE**: I have already created a [Record Set](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html) of Type A within a public hosted zone in AWS. But I still can't access `www.myDomain.com`. What may be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by following this **AWS official document**: [Routing Traffic to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html). Please note that in my case, the domain name for the EB environment included the region (e.g. my-environment.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com).

One can also use the same procedure described on another AWS document [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html).